# How to upload a file using angular JS and send it to C# web API?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I wanted to upload a file (maybe `.csv`, `.txt`, `.xls`, etc.) which contains some text, and I want the document to be processed by C#. I use Angular JS in my front end and C# for WebAPI.

I need help how to upload the file to C#?

I tried:

in C# WebAPI controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/GetCalimCsv")]
    public string GetCalimCsv(dynamic content)
    {
        return content;
    }
```

It's getting the null value.

In angular controller:

```
$scope.fileNameChanged = function (ele) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('claim', ele.files[0]);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/GetCalimCsv/',
        data: formData
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alertify.success(response.data);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        alertify.error(response.status);
    });
```

In CSHTML file:

```
<input ng-model="Claim" ng-required="true"
    type="file" accept=".js, .css, .txt, .doc, .docx, .csv, .xls | text/*"
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" />
```

sample screenshot during file input:
[JavaScript is getting the file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwe3z.png)

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am unable to get how to upload them. I am new to it.

Comment: This can help https://github.com/stewartm83/angular-fileupload-sample

Comment: Use post method of WebAPI and post via angular services.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a directive as below

```
.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
        function fn_link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChange = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            element.on('change', function (event) {
                onChange(scope, { $files: event.target.files });
            });
        };
        return {
            link: fn_link
        }
    }])
```

then replace input type=file to

```
<input type="file" id="fileId" file-model="myFiles($files)"/>
```

and then in your controller add this

```
var formData = new FormData();
        $scope.myFiles = function($files) {
            formData.append('img', $files[0]);
}
```

**Replace 'img' to a name which you want it as in backend**
**if you want to Add something ,add each and every values with keys in formData to send**
as

```
formData.append('title', form.title);
```

and your $http method

```
$http.post('YOUR SERVER API URL', formData)
```

Comment: why have you used file-model? and I tried running it, the WebAPI was unable to get data.